# How to reduce execution time in python when applying textblob correct method on csv data?

Tags: python, loops, execution, textblob

Here is my code of python where I want to correct the spelling of 'WORDS_WITHOUT_SW' column. and storing in 'CORRECT_SPELL' column. But when I give range 2 then it takes less than 1 sec. but when I give 100 then it goes in infinite. Please help me how can I solve this problem.

```
for i in range(2):
     text = df['WORDS_WITHOUT_SW'][i]
     df['CORRECT_SPELL'][i] = str(TextBlob(text).correct())
df.to_csv(str_file_name, index=False)
```

Comment: Is it infinite or is it just a long time?  It could be some spelling corrections take longer than others.  Have you tried 5 then 10 then 15 to see if it is linear?

Comment: Thanks Tim for reply. Yeah i tried 5-10-15. Yeah it takes long time and then i have to interrupt it manually. Also one thing i observed that it adds some junk rows with junk data in my database. I am not getting how to solve it.

Comment: Well, you need to remember that the spelling corrector is just a statistical analyzer.  It's making a guess, and it isn't always right.  Many people have "autocorrect" horror stories.